# Does ptrace work in user level or kernel level?

Tags: c, system-calls, strace, ptrace

I am trying to implement a Data Flow Anomaly Detection using ptrace. After a bit of research I implemented a program which is similar to strace. Now, I'm confused about this, which is what the wiki tells me about system calls:

> "System calls provide the interface between a process and the operating system"

When I am using ptrace to modify the process's memory, am I working on user space or kernel space? I'm really confused about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are operating in the address space of a separate process; this requires the intercession of (and permission from) the kernel, since independent processes cannot normally affect each others' address spaces.

Comment: Actually ptrace will generate a `int 0x80` for each system call right? So I am dealing with a interrupt so I am in kernel space right? This was my first thought. Was I wrong ?

Comment: Not exactly, it can stop the process when *it* makes a system call (which is already `int 0x80` for Linux on Intel) but it can also simply inspect process memory or registers.  Any of these however cannot be done directly to a process by another process; that second process must instead ask the kernel to act on the first, which is what `ptrace` does.

Comment: So if I want to operate directly in kernel space what should I do ??

Comment: That is usually not permitted, because it has fairly serious security implications.  Guarding and validating access to kernel capabilities (which is, when it comes down to it, full control of the system) is the *point* of system calls.  If you really want to do kernel-level operations, you would create a new system call to expose those operations to userspace, preferably with access controls so a buggy userspace process cannot damage some other process's (or worse, the kernel's own or some device's) memory.